# What program is something like this created on?

Tags: math-mode, equations, pdftex, mathtools

Been trying to further improve my LaTeX skills, and such to make my notes look better. But I was curious if you guys could easily tell what program something like this was created in?

http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~chris/NTh/Ch6_Sum2sq_Ch7_Fermat_descent.pdf

[image]

Comment: Use the `amsart` or `article` class.

Comment: The [PDF document properties](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BUZCP.png) show that it was created as a DVI, which implies a LaTeX > DVIPS > PS2PDF workflow. Also, the fonts include Computer Modern. The formatting of `\section` as centred small caps point to [`amsart`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsart).

Comment: @Werner oops sorry I was just getting those but I see you'd commented before my answer:-)

Comment: @Werner -- although `amsart` is a good suspect, it's not using the default dimensions; the default width is `30pc` and this measures `39pc`, so some adjustments have been made, either directly or through use of a package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run it with `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, `lualatex`, ... (whatever you may prefer)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[math]{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\section{foo bar and baz :-)}
\blindmathpaper

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The postscript was made with dvips(k) 5.96.1 and converted to pdf with GPL Ghostscript 8.70 It is set using Computer Modern Roman font.

(Just looking at the PDF properties in the file)